# Sonarqube 7.6 Unable to load component class org.sonar.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstyleExecutor using Gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, checkstyle

In our sonarqube upgrade attempt we are facing following issue when doing a gradle java scan which I have also filed on the sonarqube project in Github.

Is there anyone out there who might have an idea where to start resolving this? Or what I have to change from a gradle perspective.

https://github.com/checkstyle/sonar-checkstyle/issues/205

I'm on Gradle 5.3 using the sonarqube 2.7 plugin version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, just a quick shot in the dark:

In the linked issue, you state that you use SQ 7.6 and CS plugin 4.17. Those are incompatible. Try using CS plugin 4.18 or newer instead ([reference](https://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/checkstyle-compatibility-matrix.html?hl=8.17;8.18)).

Comment: Awesome that did the trick. As a reference SQ 7.6 and CS 4.18 work. As well SQ 7.7 and CS 4.18 which we decided today to include in our upgrade. Thanks for the reference.